# For any function $f>0$ with $\mu(f)<\infty$, show that $\{x|f(x)>0\}$ can be written as a union of an ascending sequence of sets of finite measure

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing

> If f is a non negative measurable function on $\mathbb R$ such that $\int f<\infty$, show that the set $\{x|f(x)>0\}$ can be written as a union of an ascending sequence of measurable sets of finite measure.

My attempt:

What I thought was setting $E_n=\{x|f(x)>\frac{1}{n}\}$. Do these sets have finite measure? Can I use $\int f<\infty$ to prove this? If so, how?

Hints and ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_{E_n}f >\dfrac{1}{n}\mu (E_n) $